# Rectangular Artifacts

Tags: rendering, normal-map, artifacts

I've been playing around with the open-source space game Endless Sky, which uses flat 2D sprites for all its spaceships but the sprites are rendered via Blender. I'm investigating the possibility of using normal mapping in the game to produce more dynamic lighting, but when I try to render normal maps for some of the ships I get weird rectangular artifacts all over the rendering:
[image: normal map with artifacts]

These are always aligned to the camera, even if I rotate the model (anti-aliasing turned off to make the artifacts more visible):
[image: ship rotated 28°]

I generated these from existing models via a python script that simply replaces all materials with a normal-mapped image:

```
img = bpy.data.images.load('./normal_tex.jpg')
tex = bpy.data.textures.new('Normals', type = 'IMAGE')
tex.image = img
mat = bpy.data.materials.new('Normals')
mtex = mat.texture_slots.add()
mtex.texture = tex
mtex.texture_coords = 'NORMAL'
mat.use_shadeless = True # ignore lighting

s = bpy.context.scene
# Apply material to all meshes in the scene
for ob in s.objects:
    if ob.type not in ['MESH', 'CURVE']:
        continue
    # Make sure to account for objects w/ 0 materials OR >1 materials
    n = len(ob.data.materials)
    ob.data.materials.clear()
    for i in range(max(n,1)):
        ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Does anyone know what would cause this or how I could fix it?